# Contour integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iz}}{(z-i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iz}}{(z-i)^2} \, \mathrm{d}z$$

I am unsure of what contour to use to evaluate this integral. I have done such integrals bounded from -infinity to infinity. Should I substitute cosz for the e^iz and use the fact that it’s an even function so that I can somehow half my result?

Comment: That just might work.

Comment: I posted a comment with an attached attempt.

Comment: Note: the integral with $\cos(iz)$ in the numerator is not equal to the real part of the integral with $e^{iz}$ in the numerator.  That denominator is not real-valued, not an even function, not an odd function.

Comment: So we cant call it an even function even though we are integrating along the real line, due to the presence of the i term? In that case i have no idea which contour to use.

Comment: You can do $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = -2\pi/e$ by this method.  But $\int_0^{+\infty}$ is not half that.

Comment: I thought so much. Thats why i tried to use the property of even functions somehow.

Comment: @GEdgar oops.  Good point.

Comment: Integrating by parts (and moving the contour) gives $Ei( i)$ where $Ei$ is the exponential integral which is a special function with no closed-form

Comment: I believe this problem was intended to be solved using standard contour integration techniques and the residue theorem

Answer (score 0):

[image: Contour Integral]

I tried this. Does this seem like the right idea?

Comment: You have computed the real part of the answer, but the value should be complex as far as I can see?

Comment: Yes although my residue calculation only produced a real number so i thought that perhaps I could only account for the real part of the integral.